# Category page with gallery for each post

Tags: categories, images, themes, gallery

I'm looking for a bit of direction on how to set up a category page (for a real estate company).

What would be the best way to have a gallery of images (1 large photo and several thumbnails) listed for each post on a category page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

install an image gallery plugin like this one http://wordpress.org/plugins/image-gallery-reloaded/ and have a gallery set in each of your posts, then edit your theme's category template and have a look at the loop, if it uses `the_excerpt()` then you have to alter it to `the_content()`.

This way, you will have a gallery list in the category list view. You may want to use another plugin, but keep the same idea.